# How to set 0 to white at a uneven color ramp

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, colorbar, matplotlib-basemap

I have an uneven color ramp and I want the 0 to be white. All negative colors have to be bluish and all positive colors have to be reddish.
My current attempted displays the 0 bluish and the 0.7 white.

Is there anyway to set the 0 to white?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors 
from matplotlib import pyplot as m

bounds_min = np.arange(-2, 0, 0.1)
bounds_max = np.arange(0, 4.1, 0.1)
bounds = np.concatenate((bounds_min, bounds_max), axis=None)       
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds, ncolors=256)      # I found this on the internet and thought this would solve my problem. But it doesn't...
m.pcolormesh(xx, yy, interpolated_grid_values, norm=norm, cmap='RdBu_r')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other answer makes it a little more complicated than it needs to be. In order to have the middle point of the colormap at 0, use a `DivergingNorm` with `vcenter=0`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import DivergingNorm

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,50,51), np.linspace(0,50,51))
z = np.linspace(-2,4,50*50).reshape(50,50)

norm = DivergingNorm(vmin=z.min(), vcenter=0, vmax=z.max())
pc = plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z, norm=norm, cmap="RdBu_r")
plt.colorbar(pc)

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Note:** From matplotlib 3.2 onwards `DivergingNorm` will be renamed to `TwoSlopeNorm`

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the desired norm, set the same number of colors on the negative as on the positive side.

Alternatively, you could use the unmodified norm, and create a special colormap. Such a colormap would have 1/3<sup>rd</sup> of blue-to-white colors and 2/3<sup>rd</sup> white-to-red colors. A benefit would be that the colorbar looks nicer. Such an approach only works if the balance between negative and positive numbers isn't too extreme.

Here is demo code with generated data. `zz` is chosen to be a sine rotated around the center, and scaled to go from -2 to 4, so symmetric around 1. At the left the image is shown with the modified colormap. At the right, the norm is changed to force white at zero.

Because of the red coloring of all positive values, the red bands are wider than the blue. In an image without changing norms nor colormaps, the bands would have equal width. The colorbars indicate the zero to be white.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-20, 20, 500)
y = np.linspace(-20, 20, 500)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zz = np.sin(np.sqrt(xx * xx + yy * yy)) * 3 + 1

negatives = -2.0
positives = 4.0

bounds_min = np.linspace(negatives, 0, 129)
bounds_max = np.linspace(0, positives, 129)[1:]
    # the zero is only needed once
    # in total there will be 257 bounds, so 256 bins
bounds = np.concatenate((bounds_min, bounds_max), axis=None)
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries=bounds, ncolors=256)

num_neg_colors = int(256 / (positives - negatives) * (-negatives))
num_pos_colors = 256 - num_neg_colors
cmap_BuRd = plt.cm.RdBu_r
colors_2neg_4pos = [cmap_BuRd(0.5*c/num_neg_colors) for c in range(num_neg_colors)] +\
                   [cmap_BuRd(1-0.5*c/num_pos_colors) for c in range(num_pos_colors)][::-1]
cmap_2neg_4pos = colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('cmap_2neg_4pos', colors_2neg_4pos, N=256)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 5))

mesh1 = ax1.pcolormesh(xx, yy, zz, cmap=cmap_2neg_4pos)
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax1.set_title('using a modified cmap')
fig.colorbar(mesh1, ax=ax1)

mesh2 = ax2.pcolormesh(xx, yy, zz, norm=norm, cmap='RdBu_r')
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.set_title('using a special norm')
ticks = np.append(np.arange(-2.0, 0, 0.25), np.arange(0, 4.001, 0.5))
fig.colorbar(mesh2, ax=ax2, ticks=ticks)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Following code plots the norm, which looks like a step function. Only with 257 bounds this step function has the correct shape everywhere (zooming to x at -2, 0 and 4).

```py
nx = np.linspace(-3,5,10000)
plt.plot(nx, norm(nx))
```

PS: There is an [alternative method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626103/custom-colormap/52626512#52626512) to create a similar colormap. But trying it out, it is clear that the `RdBu` colormap is fine-tuned and produces much better looking plots.

```py
norm_2neg_4pos = mcolors.Normalize(negatives, positives)
colors_2neg_4pos = [[0, 'blue'],
                    [norm_2neg_4pos(0.0), "white"],
                    [1, 'red']]
cmap_2neg_4pos = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", colors_2neg_4pos)
```

Still another simple solution is rescaling everything between -4 and 4. However, this would lose the darker blues. An alternative to 'RdBu_r' is 'seismic' with a different way to run from red over white to blue.

```py
ax.pcolormesh(xx, yy, zz, vmin=-positives, vmax=positives, cmap='RdBu_r')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It took me a while to get it right, but now it works. Do you know if it is possible to have the negative bar shorter than the positive bar?

Comment: Yes, that can also be done. In that case, the norm is not needed, only the colormap needs to be recalculated. It won't work well if there is a huge difference between negative and positive, but with a factor of 2 it would work well. Give me some time to create an example.